# 6x7 Pokemon-based cipher

Tags: cipher, visual

My friend made this cipher for me to solve and it has me stumped. Wondered if anyone else would want to take a crack at it. All it is is this image:

[image]

Names of the pokemon in order are (assuming I identified them correctly):

```
Altaria Remoraid Exploud Flaaffy Igglybuff Nidorina
Ivysaur Vulpix Sceptile Illumise Tyranitar  Illumise
Vibrava Feebas Onix Ralts Aipom Glalie
Exploud Nidoking Igglybuff Venonat Dugtrio Nidorino
Armaldo Masquerain Ursaring Venonat Igglybuff Torchic
Articuno Salamence Machop Unown Illumise Lombre
Aggron Articuno Huntail Tentacruel Ivysaur Whismur
```

With the first letters:

```
AREFIN
IVSITI
VFORAG
ENIVDN
AMUVIT
ASMUIL
AAHTIW
```

With the last letters:

```
ADDYFA
RXEERE
ASXSME
DGFTOO
ONGTFC
OEPNEE
NOLLRR
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the first letter of each pokemon name, because the first three, Altaria, Remoraid, and Exploud make ARE, or looking at the pokemon types? If you have a list of the names, that may be helpful because myself (and probably a lot of others) do not know all of these names.

Comment: Added to the question! Checking the letters was my first idea, but no matter how I shift them around, I can't get it to spell anything...

Comment: Maybe the type of pokemon has something to do with it...

Comment: There are so many beginning with duplicate letters (e.g. A = Altaria, Aipom, Articuno, Aggron, ...) I would suspect the secret lies elsewhere. Is there potentially anything in using something unique like their Pokedex numbers instead? (e.g. first line is 314-223-295-180-174-30) Note that all are Gen III or earlier too - possibly something in that?

Comment: Saying that, by my count there are 34 different Pokemon in this image, meaning that we're not looking for uniqueness at all - you *will* have multiple Pokemon representing the same letters (if each picture translates to a letter...).

Comment: There are 23 unique types, so that could be a substitution, but with only 42 letters and no punctuation or spacing, decrypting seems impossible. Dex numbers seems likely, since there are repeated individual pokemon, but I don't know any 3-digit codes, and there are still 34 different #s. Them all starting with 0-3 is a great catch, but I can't think of what it could mean

Comment: Only hint I could get was that the grid arrangement was important

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

I'm not a big pokemon buff, but I noticed some terms could be made out from the grid of first letters.

This included:

> REFIN IV

- Refine IV? Googled, its an actual process in the game.

> VSITI

- Visit

> FORAGE

- Forage (the ability)

> SMUILA

- Simulate

> HTIW

- with

It sounds like steps to get something done in a game. If you share a common interest in a pokemon game with you friend, that might hold clues.